# SQL Server 2008 R2 - UPDATE with SELECT on same table as part of query

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I've been trying for weeks to figure out an issue that happens once every 100,000+ transactions. I've tried dozens of variations and have run out of ideas, so I'm hoping someone has seen this before.

In summary, I have a table that acts like a queue. Records are inserted either singly or in transaction'ed batches, and sometimes one record is "dependent" on another (so that it is not eligible to be removed from the queue until the record it's dependent on is first removed). The basic structure of the tables includes these columns:

- `item_id` - a GUID that uniquely identifies the record
- `depend_id` - a GUID that identifies the record that this record is dependent on (or NULL if it's not dependent on anything)
- `item_lock` - a GUID that starts out NULL, but is set to the "owner process" when the record is "locked down" to be worked on (when the work is done, the record is deleted from the table)

A simplified version of the polling query that is called to "lock down" the next "ready" record is:

```
UPDATE TOP(1) Q1 SET
  lock_id = @lock,
  FROM item_queue Q1
WHERE (lock_id IS NULL)
AND (depend_id IS NULL OR depend_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM item_queue))
AND execute_at < GETUTCDATE()
```

My objective here (and this works almost all of the time) is that the NOT IN SELECT will simply check to see if the item that is otherwise eligible to have its lock_id set, that it won't be chosen if it's depend_id matches another item that's still in the table. But 1 out of 100,000+ calls to the stored procedure, that constraint fails and the record with the depend_id that does match an item_id that's still in the table gets chosen.

I have tried various alternatives to the NOT IN SELECT; all methods "work" but all fail in the same way. It is always the case that "dependent" records are inserted with their dependencies within a committed transaction.

Any and all ideas welcomed...I'm stumped.

PS - I should mention that there are many different threads on different client machines adding to and polling/locking/deleting records in this table. One of my working theories is that there is some sort of locking/contention that occasionally causes the record that is being depended on to not show up in the NOT IN SELECT subquery, causing the dependent record to become eligible (but I have not been able to come up with the specific scenario for that to happen).

**EDIT:** More on transaction isolation level: I'm running with the default READ COMMITTED isolation level. Is it possible that this is causing the "depended on" record to be omitted from the NOT IN SELECT subquery in the "race condition" case where another thread has just updated it? If so, I'm not entirely clear on what isolation level I need to ensure that any record that's still in the table (whether it's being updated or not) comes back in that query.

Comment: Hint: do you have multiple processes inserting/reading? transaction isolation level

Comment: @Mitch: Yes (just thought to add that note). I've been studying the transaction isolation level, but I can't quite come up with a scenario that should or shouldn't work. This issue has proven very hard to test, since it happens so infrequently.

Comment: @user640466 So what are the transaction isolation levels for different processes that use the table in question? Without knowing that it's rather hard to help you...

Comment: @Szymon: All transactions that touch this table are using the default isolation level of READ COMMITTED.

Comment: It makes me wonder if adding a NOLOCK hint to the subquery would do the trick? Essentially, as I understand it, this would make that query act like READ UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: In researching the idea of adding a NOLOCK hint, I've found a few articles that say there are scenarios where NOLOCK will cause duplicate rows (which is fine in this case) and missing rows (which is what I'm trying to avoid), so that's not looking very promising.

Comment: I really don't like the NOLOCK idea. Any indexes on table? Maybe you're selecting from Index while deleting from table, and index is not updated yet.

Comment: @OlehNechytailo: Yes, the more I read about the NOLOCK hint, the less I like it for this use-case. Regarding indexes, I've tried it both ways--with no index on item_id (since this table is always fairly small--a few 100 records at most) and with a secondary index on item_id. Both ways have the same effect. But I'm not sure it matters: The "dependent on" record is always there before the dependent record, so it's not a matter of it (or the index) being updated or not, I think it's a matter of it being missing from the SELECT, probably because it was just updated by another thread.

Comment: Crazy idea - table lock. But it looks like nuking house with termites. Maybe I'll come later with better idea.

Comment: What is your purpose of the TOP(1) item_queue, and if you can show some sample data of what you have, and what you WANT to occur during the single update call might help too.

Comment: @DRapp: The purpose of the TOP(1) is so that each call to the stored procedure will "choose" one eligible record to be worked on by the calling process. It does this by updating that record, setting a unique identifier into the lock_id column. Once lock_id is set, the record is ineligible for any other thread until the working thread is through with it (at which point it either deletes it or sets lock_id back to NULL, which would allow another thread to pick it up later). All of that works (99.999% of the time).

Comment: I've been studying and trying different transaction isolation levels, including SNAPSHOT, but so far everything is either no better or simply non-functional. The root issue here seems to be that there are cases where rows in a result set will be "missing", specifically if another thread updates but has not yet committed the record that is "depended on", the "dependent" record becomes selectable because the "depended on" record does not exist in the subquery (or the join). I even tried a separate table of item_ids, managed by triggers on the main queue, used that for the subquery; still fails.

Comment: Here is one of several articles I've found on the problem with missing "dirty" rows in a select. This one talks about READ COMMITTED and suggests SNAPSHOT (which I've tried, but get an error instead): [link](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/10/missing-committed-rows-in-read.html)

Comment: The root issue here appears to revolve around various "loopholes" that cause a result set to not return dirty rows; the result being that if the "depends on" record happens to be dirty at the time the test is made, it's missing, so the "dependent" record is clear to go. Is there not some way to make SQL server return the dirty rows (and from what I've read and seen, it's no NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED isolation)?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing as a correlated update?  By left-joining to the item queue table the second time by the depend_id to the item_id, you should not be locking anything in the second instance, and have the criteria just see if that left join result is NULL.  If the depend_id was null, then it won't find a match via the left-join.  If it DID have a value in depend_id, and not in as an item_id value, then it too would result in null.  Only if the depend_id MATCHED and ITEM_ID would it NOT BE NULL and thus excluded from consideration.

```
UPDATE TOP(1) item_queue 
   SET lock_id = @lock
  FROM item_queue
     LEFT JOIN item_queue IQ2
        ON item_queue.depend_id = IQ2.item_id
  WHERE
         lock_id is null
     AND IQ2.item_id is null
     AND execute_at < GETUTCDATE()
```

Comment: I had not tried this particular approach, but it looks interesting. I'm a bit confused by the logic though. IQ2.item_id will never be NULL; all records always have an item_id. depend_id may be NULL (and usually is); it's only non-NULL if that record depends on another. I'm not sure how to express that logic in the JOIN. That's what led me to using the subquery. I need to check that no item_id equals the target record's depend_id (and if the depend_id is NULL, that's fine, because no item_id will ever be NULL).

Comment: @user640466, Yes, all item Ids will have a value, but that is why I was trying to follow your sub-select query.  By joining on the DEPEND ID to the Item_ID -- per your Depend_ID not in ( select item_id from item queue)

Comment: I've been playing with this concept in my sandbox and I can't come up with any solution that works.

Comment: @user640466, then in your sandbox, turn it into a SELECT Query to see if you can get records that meet the criteria you are looking for.  If that doesn't work, neither will the UPDATE.  Get the criteria / join working first, THEN apply it with the UPDATE.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually, I found a version that does seem to work. I need to run some more tests, but it looks promising.

Comment: A version very close to your example is working quite well. It's deceptively simple and according to the execution plan, is more efficient than using the subquery. It took me a while to wrap my head around it, but so far so good. I'm going to deploy it to one production server and watch it through the day tomorrow. Keeping my fingers crossed!

Comment: No joy. Under production load, the same thing happens with the JOIN approach (it could actually be worse). I've gone back to the SELECT subquery for now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification of your Top(1), I might switch where the locking attempt might be done by doing the following... Pseudocode within your thread...

```
Select All Pending Possible Item_Queue entries.
scan through the list of records returned
   update the lock_id = uniqueGUID
      where item queue ID is the one you are working with LOCALLY
        AND lock_id IS NULL

   if the number of records returned = 1, then you got it.
      process the item queue ID you successfully "locked"
   else
      if it comes back 0 records updated, someone else hit it 
      before you... continue with next available LOCAL record.

end scan of available LOCAL POSSIBLE queue records
```

The premise is this.  Everyone queries all POSSIBLE queue items, and everyone tries to hit an update with their GUID.  Since the update call here is specifically looking to update where the LOCK_ID IS NULL, if someone else hit it first, it is no longer null and won't update it (0 records updated).  If so, try the next one and go through the list.

If no records are available after scanning through the entire available list, you may want to wrap that in a loop of say 2-3 times by getting a fresh list each cycle to remove any "in process" items now being processed and a fresh list of available to try with.

Other similar approaches have been to update with a numeric counter for a lock column and to set it to 1 more than the last value where the value equals what you originally retrieved (vs null in this case).  This way, it allows a sort of tracker to how many TIMES a given record has been locked for updating.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your suggestion, the scanning would be happening within the client code, not on the SQL server?

Comment: @user640466, correct, even if you pull down a limit of say 25 possible queue entries LOCALLY that are all NULL for a lock ID.  You try to set the GUID to one at a time until one DOES get updated, hence your qualifier on the update is still LOCK_ID IS NULL.  If someone else gets a lock assigned while you are pulling down, your version should fail getting that lock assigned for YOU.  If none of the ex: 25 records work, get a fresh pull of queue entries to work, especially if the queue could have 1000's of entries needing to be processed.

Comment: Understood. I can see how this could work, but I honestly hope I don't have to go this route. It seems a little klunky and adds a lot more transactions (especially since there are a dozen or more threads all competing for rows in this table--I can see a high percentage of "failed" lock attempts due to this contention). I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm still hoping there is a way to get the SQL server to consistently return all rows.

Comment: @user640466, yes, but for scratching your head for weeks, and considering other alternatives, I wanted to throw it into the ring for consideration.  Only one LOCK should actually get assigned anyhow at any given time, and until someone wins for a given ID you now have one less out of the cycle.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I appreciate it, and may ultimately end up going this way; just hoping not to.

Comment: @user640466, as a possible help if this route, you can always return the result set in a RAND() order, so nobody is getting the exact same order of results returned, so first record for each user could completely be different and lower the failed update attempts.

Comment: Good idea; I had thought about doing something similar (I usually sort by NEWID()). I have a vague memory of RAND() being the same value when it's used in a query--maybe that's on an ancient version of SQL Server?